# Adding multiple buttons to a cart using php

Tags: php

I need two buttons to show up after a product is added to a cart on an e commerce site.Here is how the code reads now:

```
// Output success messages
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) :
    $return_to  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );
    $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ), $added_text );
else :
    $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ), __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), $added_text );
endif;
wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ) );
}
```

I want both the "Continue Shopping" and View Cart buttons to show up.

Answer (score 0):

So if I am understanding correctly, this would display the Cart and Continue shopping buttons together:

```
// Output success messages
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) :
      $return_to  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ?         wp_get_referer() : home_url() );
      $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ), $added_text );
      $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ), __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), $added_text );
else :
      $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ), __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), $added_text );
endif;
wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ) );
```